# Calculating by group based on previous and current row in R

Tags: r, row

I can make calculations based on previous and current row in R.

In case of this dataframe(df):

```
    A B 
[1] 2 2 
[2] 2 3 
[3] 4 5.5 
... 

B2 = A2 + 0.5*B1
```

I can calculate this function by using this code.

```
for( i in 2:nrow(df) ) { 
        B[i] <- 1/2 * B[i-1] + df$A[i] 
}
```

However, I have an Id(group) in my dataset, so I need to calculate this function by id.

```
    id A B
[1] 1  0 0
[2] 1  2 2 
[3] 1  2 3
[4] 2  1 1 
[5] 2  4 4.5
[6] 2  4 6.25 
... 

B2 = A2 + 0.5*B1
B4 = A4 + 0.5*0 (becasue id is changed)
B5 = A5 + 0.5*B4 
...
```

How can I handle this problem in R?
Thanks.

Comment: The `plyr` package may be a good start or use `split` to split on ID and then `lapply` to apply you code to each piece then use `do.call` with `rbind` to put it all back together.

Comment: Thnak you for your comment. However, my dataset has a lot of IDs(over 1,000,000). So, I think that your advice takes too much time. Is there any other effective approache?

Comment: The `data.table` package is usually good for these sorts of problems.  However, a vectorized solution may be possible if I understood what you're doing.  Should B 4 be 2.5?  How many groups are there?

Comment: B4 is 1 becasue id is changed. While B3 is value of id1, B4 is value of id2. Logically, B4 do not have a previous row. Thus, B4 is 1. As I mentioned earler, I have approximatively 1,000,000 ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems like the result of each step depends on the previous one in the way you're doing it now, getting rid of the `for` loop appears tricky. I'm wondering if something like this is fast enough:

```
require(data.table)
require(compiler)

df <- data.table(df)

f <- function(A, B) {
  for(i in seq_along(B)[-1]) {
    B[i] <- 0.5 * B[i - 1L] + A[i]
  }

  B
}

g <- cmpfun(f)

df[, B := g(A, B), by = id]
```