# Rebuild client history based on previous observations in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I am attempting to build a client history of events based on previous rows.  I have a working solution, however I have 10million observations, and it takes over 5 days to run (which is an unworkable solution).  I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish my goal.

here is a sample data set:

```
AccountID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
INVOICE <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
INVOICEDATE <- as.Date(c('3/1/2015','9/1/2015', '3/1/2016', '9/1/2016', '3/1/2017'
                         , '9/1/2017', '3/1/2016', '9/1/2016'
                         , '3/1/2017', '9/1/2017', '3/1/2015', '9/1/2015'
                         , '3/1/2016', '9/1/2016', '3/1/2017', '9/1/2017', '3/1/2018')
                       , format="%m/%d/%Y")
ZeroBalanceDate <- as.Date(c('6/1/2015','12/1/2015', '5/1/2016', '9/1/2016', NA
                         , '11/1/2017', '8/1/2016', '9/1/2017'
                         , NA, '12/1/2017', '7/1/2015', '12/1/2015'
                         , '4/1/2016', '11/1/2016', '4/1/2017', NA, NA)
                       , format="%m/%d/%Y")
Bankruptcy <- c(1, 82, 0, 38, 0, 37, 0, 0, 21, 11, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Charity <- c(87, 94, 0, 0, 34, 88, 86, 0, 0, 94, 19, 20, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Payment <- c(30, 0, 29, 91, 63, 73, 99, 47, 24, 94, 36, 72, 1, 20, 69, 0, 0)
Prev_Bankruptcy <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Prev_Charity <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Prev_Payment <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
FINAL_DF <- data.frame(AccountID, INVOICE, INVOICEDATE, ZeroBalanceDate, Bankruptcy, 
                       Charity, Payment, Prev_Bankruptcy, Prev_Charity, Prev_Payment)
```

this is my current solution:

```
AccountIDlist <- as.list(FINAL_DF$AccountID) %>% unique()
for (i in 1:length(AccountIDlist)) {
  tmpdf <- NULL
  tmpdf <- FINAL_DF[FINAL_DF$AccountID == AccountIDlist[[i]], ] 
  tmpdf <- tmpdf[order(as.Date(tmpdf$INVOICEDATE, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
  
  if (nrow(tmpdf) > 1) {
    for (j in 2:nrow(tmpdf)) {
      tmpdf[j,]$Prev_Bankruptcy <- ifelse(tmpdf[j-1,]$Bankruptcy > 0, tmpdf[j-1,]$Prev_Bankruptcy + 1, tmpdf[j-1,]$Prev_Bankruptcy)
      tmpdf[j,]$Prev_Charity <- ifelse(tmpdf[j-1,]$Charity > 0, tmpdf[j-1,]$Prev_Charity + 1, tmpdf[j-1,]$Prev_Charity)
      tmpdf[j,]$Prev_Payment <- ifelse(!is.na(tmpdf[j-1,]$ZeroBalanceDate), tmpdf[j-1,]$Prev_Payment + 1, tmpdf[j-1,]$Prev_Payment)
    }
    
    for (j in 1:nrow(tmpdf)) {
      FINAL_DF[FINAL_DF$INVOICE == tmpdf[j,]$INVOICE,]$Prev_Bankruptcy <- tmpdf[j,]$Prev_Bankruptcy
      FINAL_DF[FINAL_DF$INVOICE == tmpdf[j,]$INVOICE,]$Prev_Charity <- tmpdf[j,]$Prev_Charity
      FINAL_DF[FINAL_DF$INVOICE == tmpdf[j,]$INVOICE,]$Prev_Payment <- tmpdf[j,]$Prev_Payment
    }
  }
}
```

The output should look like this:
[image: sample dataframe]

This person had a similar question:
[Calculating by group based on previous and current row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393499/calculating-by-group-based-on-previous-and-current-row-in-r)
However, there was no real workable solution posted.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### dplyr

I think this is a great example of `dplyr` making something much more readable.

```r
library(dplyr)
FINAL_DF %>%
  group_by(AccountID) %>%
  mutate(
    Prev_Bankruptcy = c(0, cumsum(Bankruptcy > 0)[-n()]),
    Prev_Charity = c(0, cumsum(Charity > 0)[-n()]),
    Prev_Payment = c(0, cumsum(!is.na(ZeroBalanceDate))[-n()])
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 17 x 10
#    AccountID INVOICE INVOICEDATE ZeroBalanceDate Bankruptcy Charity Payment Prev_Bankruptcy Prev_Charity Prev_Payment
#        <dbl>   <dbl> <date>      <date>               <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1         1       1 2015-03-01  2015-06-01               1      87      30               0            0            0
#  2         1       2 2015-09-01  2015-12-01              82      94       0               1            1            1
#  3         1       3 2016-03-01  2016-05-01               0       0      29               2            2            2
#  4         1       4 2016-09-01  2016-09-01              38       0      91               2            2            3
#  5         1       5 2017-03-01  NA                       0      34      63               3            2            4
#  6         1       6 2017-09-01  2017-11-01              37      88      73               3            3            4
#  7         2       7 2016-03-01  2016-08-01               0      86      99               0            0            0
#  8         2       8 2016-09-01  2017-09-01               0       0      47               0            1            1
#  9         2       9 2017-03-01  NA                      21       0      24               0            1            2
# 10         2      10 2017-09-01  2017-12-01              11      94      94               1            1            2
# 11         3      11 2015-03-01  2015-07-01              34      19      36               0            0            0
# 12         3      12 2015-09-01  2015-12-01               0      20      72               1            1            1
# 13         3      13 2016-03-01  2016-04-01               0      22       1               1            2            2
# 14         3      14 2016-09-01  2016-11-01               0       0      20               1            3            3
# 15         3      15 2017-03-01  2017-04-01               0       0      69               1            3            4
# 16         3      16 2017-09-01  NA                       0       0       0               1            3            5
# 17         3      17 2018-03-01  NA                       0       0       0               1            3            5
```

### data.table

If performance is still an issue, you might consider shifting to `data.table` where its referential semantics can provide a significant performance improvement.

```r
library(data.table)
FINAL_DT[, c("Prev_Bankruptcy", "Prev_Charity", "Prev_Payment") :=
             .(c(0, cumsum(Bankruptcy > 0)[-.N]),
               c(0, cumsum(Charity > 0)[-.N]),
               c(0, cumsum(!is.na(ZeroBalanceDate))[-.N])),
         by = .(AccountID)]
#     AccountID INVOICE INVOICEDATE ZeroBalanceDate Bankruptcy Charity Payment Prev_Bankruptcy Prev_Charity Prev_Payment
#         <num>   <num>      <Date>          <Date>      <num>   <num>   <num>           <num>        <num>        <num>
#  1:         1       1  2015-03-01      2015-06-01          1      87      30               0            0            0
#  2:         1       2  2015-09-01      2015-12-01         82      94       0               1            1            1
#  3:         1       3  2016-03-01      2016-05-01          0       0      29               2            2            2
#  4:         1       4  2016-09-01      2016-09-01         38       0      91               2            2            3
#  5:         1       5  2017-03-01            <NA>          0      34      63               3            2            4
#  6:         1       6  2017-09-01      2017-11-01         37      88      73               3            3            4
#  7:         2       7  2016-03-01      2016-08-01          0      86      99               0            0            0
#  8:         2       8  2016-09-01      2017-09-01          0       0      47               0            1            1
#  9:         2       9  2017-03-01            <NA>         21       0      24               0            1            2
# 10:         2      10  2017-09-01      2017-12-01         11      94      94               1            1            2
# 11:         3      11  2015-03-01      2015-07-01         34      19      36               0            0            0
# 12:         3      12  2015-09-01      2015-12-01          0      20      72               1            1            1
# 13:         3      13  2016-03-01      2016-04-01          0      22       1               1            2            2
# 14:         3      14  2016-09-01      2016-11-01          0       0      20               1            3            3
# 15:         3      15  2017-03-01      2017-04-01          0       0      69               1            3            4
# 16:         3      16  2017-09-01            <NA>          0       0       0               1            3            5
# 17:         3      17  2018-03-01            <NA>          0       0       0               1            3            5
```

Comment: Using data tables works amazingly fast.  A little over 1 minute.
Is there a way to use data tables to do the summing based on two criteria?
Something like (i tried this it does not work)

c(0, cumsum((!is.na(ZeroBalanceDate) && (as.Date(INVOICEDATE ) > (as.Date(Sys.Date() - (365*5+30)))))  )[-.N])

Comment: (1) `&&` should almost never be used in vectorized operations, you might need `&` but I need to look at it more. (2) `INVOICEDATE` is already a `Date` class, and `Sys.Date()` is *always* `Date` class, stop using `as.Date`. Fix those and it might work.

Comment: You can also use `(Sys.Date() - INVOICEDATE) > (365*5+30)` or something like that